# Extracting strings from object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm sure this is incredibly obvious but I am a beginner at PHP. I am simply trying to pull some data from an object, store that data in an array and assign that array to `$_SESSION[]`. The data is a username and user id.

However it is currently not working.

The rest of the code is working fine. There are values in `$user->id;` and `$user->user;`. I just can't seem to stick them into `$s_id` and `$s_user`.

User.php is also working correctly I just included it for reference.

login.php:

```
<?php // login.php
require_once("user.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
session_start();

$_SESSION['userid'] = ''; // Force a logout
$r_userid = $_REQUEST['userid'];
$r_passwd = $_REQUEST['passwd'];
$result = array();
$result['success'] = false;
if (isset($r_userid) && ($r_userid != '') && isset($r_passwd) && ($r_passwd != '')) {
    $user = User::findOnIdPassword($r_userid, $r_passwd);
    if ($user) {
        $s_id = $user->id; 
        $s_user = $user->user;
        $_SESSION['userid'] = array($s_id, $s_user);
        $result['message'] = "Successful Login";
        $result['success'] = true;
    } else {
        $result['message'] = "Login Failed, please try again";
    }
} else {
    $result['message'] = "Missing User id and password";
}
print(json_encode($result));
?>
```

user.php:

```
<?php // user.php
require_once "sql.php";

Class User {
private $id;
private $user;
private $email;
private $password;

public function __construct($id, $user, $password, $email) {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->email = $email;
}

public function insert() {
    $query = "insert into Users (username, password, email) values"
             . "('$this->user', '$this->password', '$this->email');";
    $result = Sql::query($query);
    return $result;
}

public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

public function getEmail() {
    return $this->email;
}

public static function findOnIdPassword($user, $passwd) {
    $query = "select * from Users where username = '$user' and password = '$passwd';";
    if ($result = Sql::query($query)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 1) {
            $result = null;
        } else {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $id = $row['id'];
            $user = $row['username'];
            $password = $row['password'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $result = new User($id, $user, $password, $email);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

// findOnEmail(email)
// update(newEmail, newPassword)
// findAll for admin
}

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `id` and `user` are private, which is why you can't seem to stick them to `$s_id` and `$s_user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties you want to access are private. But for $id there is a method you can use to extract data:

```
$s_id = $user->getId();
```

For the user you can create an extra get method in user.php inside the user class:

```
public function getUser(){
    return $this->user;
}
```

And then use it in login.php:

```
$s_user = $user->getUser();
```

But as for your code in particular, I can't see the reason to extract the username through the User object. I see that $r_userid is used as an actual value of $user argument for User::findOnIdPassword($user, $passwd) method where it is applied in SQL "WHERE username='$user'" clause. And there $user is again extracted as username field from database. So if SQL query succeeds you will have equal values in both $r_userid and $s_user.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Even more so than the previous answer!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to access a property outside a class that is private. Here:

```
$s_id = $user->id; 
$s_user = $user->user;
```

You should instead use getId() and create another method to get the username:

```
$s_id = $user->getId();
$s_user = $user->getUser();
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! I figured it would be something like that.